# Manga/Anime of two female secret/military agents featuring countless upskirt moments

Tags: agent-aika

I remember an anime that was broadcasted somewhere between 2002 and 2006 on the German MTV.
It was about two female agents if I remember correctly that were members of some secret/military organization.

The most noticeable part is the countless upskirts and bra flashes the series showed, never anything more revealing.

One of the two females is rather small and both mainly use simple handguns in combat. Can someone help me find the animes name?

***edit***

writing these details down, bopped a title to my head.. [Noir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noir_%28anime%29).. But I'm not quite sure yet and I can't verify that right now, as I am in the office.

Comment: I don't think Noir has a single upskirt shot. And definitely not countless.

Comment: ...all of them?

Comment: could it be Excel Saga?

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Could it be [Agent Aika](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=102)? It features the main character (older woman) Aika and her partner Rion. There's a **lot** of fan service, especially panty shots and bra shots. It was released as an OVA in 1997 but was aired on several German TV channels.

The [character designs practically make it impossible not to see panties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1Zvm.jpg)

More info:

- [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=102)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_Aika)
- [MyAnime List](http://myanimelist.net/anime/366/Agent_Aika)
- [Agent Aika Wikia](http://agentaika.wikia.com/wiki/Agent_Aika)

Comment: I also think Aika is the most likely candidate. Although OP said "nothing more revealing" than panty- and bra shots. IIRC Aika also had a few topless scenes. It might have been a censored cut, though.

Answer (score 8):

I also find Aika to be the most likely candidate as it is the epitome of the panty shot anime.

However, there is also another candidate which fits the description: Aika's spiritual successor *Najica Blitz Tactics* which ran on the other German music TV station Viva in 2004.

[image]

Produced by the same studio (Fantasia) under the same director (Katsuhiko Nishijima) as Aika, it also features an older and a younger female agent and lots and lots of panty shots. However, the most memorable difference is that the younger character is an android (gynoid?) whose character development gets much story focus (not as much as her underwear, though).

More info:

- [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=420)
- [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/anime/321/Najica_Dengeki_Sakusen)
- [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/NajicaBlitzTactics)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Najica_Blitz_Tactics)

Comment: And when I may post a personal opinion: I consider it far superior to Aika in story, visuals **and** fanservice and it is a pity that this anime never reached the same cult status as Aika. Maybe that's because Aika was "so bad it's good" while Najika pushed the quality into "so OK it's average" territory.

Answer (score 2):

*Aika* and *Najica* are the most likely answers -- *Noir* has handguns, short skirts and occasional fanservice, but zero panty shots -- but I have a third guess:

## Kiddy Grade

[image: Kiddy Grade]

*Kiddy Grade* is a 2002 science fiction series about two superpowered interstellar secret agents for the Galactic Organization for Trade and Tariffs, Éclair and Lumière. It's pretty heavy on the fanservice early on, and they largely fight with handguns — along with super-lipstick, robots and a spaceship, anyway.

- [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=891)
- [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/anime/274/Kiddy_Grade)
- [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/KiddyGrade)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiddy_Grade)

Comment: The show never ran on German TV, though.

Comment: @Philipp Huh. Well, it should have! Thanks for the information. :)